# AAPT error: resource drawable/... not found

Tags: android, resources, aapt, aapt2

After recently upgrading my android studio, I am not able to build my project anymore.

Every time I execute a build, I am struck with the following error:

```
error: resource drawable/splash_screen (aka com.whereisthemonkey.nowalism:drawable/splash_screen) not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource drawable/splash_screen (aka com.whereisthemonkey.nowalism:drawable/splash_screen) not found., sources=[C:\Users\Lucas\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\cf575568f869a44c685b16e47de83a28\res\values\values.xml:1632:5-84], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

This error persists, even though the file splash_screen.xml exists under the drawable folder.

Rebuilding, cleaning the project and invalidating caches did not work!

Adding the line android.enableAapt2=false does not resolve the real issue and I would therefore rather find the root of the problem.

The following shows my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'//https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1939

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whereisthemonkey.nowalism"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    // Keep the following configuration in order to target Java 8.
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs += [
                    'src/main/res-backgrounds',
                    'src/main/res-jobs',
            ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

    //Do not update due to dex error
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

    //Do not update due to dex error
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'

    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'

    implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.4.1'

    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.12.0'
    //Do not update due to dex error
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'//https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1939

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it is in drawable folder or in some drawable-xyz folder. Please share screenshot of directory structure

Comment: It is definitly in the main drawable folder located under src/main/res/drawable/splash_screen.xml. Changing the location in any kind did unfortunately not help

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I fixed the error, which was probably coming from a mal-formatted copied XML file (probably some line-ending confusion)

Rewriting those fixed the error, although Android Studio displayed another file as the source of the problem, which in fact had nothing to do with the error itself.

Comment: I had a similar error which was caused due to a malformed xml. Unfortunately Android studio did not display a warning.

Comment: I have a lot of xml files... how can I find the mal-formed one?

Comment: Thank you. I have faced the same problem above.

Answer (score 142):

In my case it was an xml selector. In the first line I had two of these (thanks to copy paste among my files):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and Android Studio didn't give any warning or something. Removing it fixed the problem but it needed a full clean build afterwards.

Comment: Note this may not be in the file that apparently gives the error! Check any XML files you recently added or modified in the project.

Comment: so officially debug output are not reliable and not self explanatory

Comment: Project was unable to build. I did this. Compiled successfully. Removed the line again, rebuilt the project, now it works. Whatever...

Comment: I used a SVG validator and fixed my issues.

Comment: I had this error because it was *missing* the `<?xml` line

Answer (score 11):

In my case
I deleted namespace declaration duplicate like `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` 
and I used  Analyse -> inspect code tool to show the error in the log, then I resolved the error in other files xml in drawable resource.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue and finally solve this by

> Analyze>Inspect Code

My Application was missing ending tags in one of the XML File Just Try **Analyze > Inspect Code** it will redirect you to the exact error.

Answer (score 4):

in my case i  like this :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

so i just remove one of them

Answer (score 3):

Check your each and every XML and maybe you will find the following situation.

- While coping code or files from other projects, maybe you forgot to add some resources like drawable, strings.
- Check each drawable files, may **Android Studio** will highlight when you open that file.

Sometimes this type of error we have to find because of Android Studio stuck with errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it when I added my icons in the drawable file to 24dp.

Copy any icon you want and paste it in the drawable file, and it will create (by default) 24dp icons.

Answer (score 3):

If you got down here and yet didn't got the answer so you might need to use `mipmap`. It's used to **find the assets related to the target device dpi** (like: mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, ...).

So all you need to do is to address the asset from the `mipmap` instead of `drawable`.

`android:resource="@mipmap/splash_screen"`

Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and where ever you used `drawable` change it to `mipmap`. here is some example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a duplicated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in a drawable ressource file

Comment: 100% right, you saved my day thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was a drawable resource file that required a higher API version as it was my minSdkVersion set in build.gradle. The main problem was that the file did not show any error until you opened it, so it was hard to find it at all. I have spent at least 4 hours trying other things, since as an error when building the project it showed other drawable resource files that did not have any problems at all. After removing the drawable that required the higher API the app built normally.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was malformed splash_screen.xml which was part of "reverted commit" which actually deleted this file, but somehow it was still may be it was in active changelist.

Fixed that file and solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is code conflict, other person changed the same file with me. The resource code is changed. When I fix the file, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: There was a file that I did not create inside a drawable file, and this file was empty and I just deleted it and the program started

Answer (score 1):

If you have put together your own icon ready for store release, be sure not to include the extension of the icon in your xml file. it will always fail. in my case it was this..

```
 <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/myAppSplashLogo.png"/>
```

and the right way to do it is to remove the .png extension.

```
 <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/myAppSplashLogo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had made drawable files that were all debug classification and had to go back and make a release classification equivalent. After doing this it worked on the first try.

Comment: Excellent answer that is simple and works.  Just copy debug folder content into release folder.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Go to app folder and delete build folder
2 - Click on File -> Invalide Caches - Invalide and Restart

Answer (score 1):

in my case under drawable folder i changed the image which is declared same in androidmanifest file

Answer (score 1):

removing .png from  `android:icon="@drawable/ic_bg.png">` solved my issue

Comment: works with flutter splash screen lol ty

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while building a release version of my app the problem was that i had some important `res` files of my project inside the `debug` directory instead of having them inside the `release` dir so i fixed the problem by moving the files that were in `debug` inside `release` you can check it by viewing your project tree under `project` instead of `android`

Answer (score 0):

while copy and pasting code I also pasted below line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Since,my xml file already contain above line and  on adding this line it appear twice .

so I remove one of these line and it resolve my error

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I used a wrong reference to the android resource file 
i.e  `android:color/splash_bg` instead of `@color/splash_bg`

where `splash_bg` represents  my custom color resource declared in res/values/colors.xml  file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove `android:src="@drawable/background"` and `android:src="@drawable/logo"` lines from splash_screen.xml although the error was originally pointing at AndroidManifest.xml.

And like the first post is saying, make sure the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is correct in all xml files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had deleted the folder "drawable"

Answer (score 0):

I reformated code (since I didn't find error) in one of xml (vector) files that wasn't mentioned in error (I think) as mentioned also by @Lucas Romier, but file name was underlined red and it suggested then clean build and it worked then. :)

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was that i misspelled the names of `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, etc. (I wrote them as `dawable-mdpi`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case `File > Invalidate Caches`, `Build > Rebuild Project`, removing `.gradle` folder didn't help. So I removed a folder `res\mipmap-anydpi-v26` that contained a conflicting file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it by manually adding

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
}
```

even after linking with react-native. Also added

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);  // Added this
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , I noticed while debugging the code it worked perfectly but during reliease then the bug would persist .

I f you are facing the same issue don't worry , It means the image has been saved  on debug mode and to fix the issue go to **FILE - NEW - IMAGE ASSET** (don't change anything just click next on top where you see)  res directory change it from **DEBUG** to **MAIN** . your image asset can now be used on both release and debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you copy and past any kind of drawable to your project directly to Android Studio, it stored in Debug Drawable, just move by File Explorer from Debug Resources to Main Resources.

From `\app\src\debug\res\drawable`

To  `\app\src\main\res\drawable`

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when your assets are not bundled properly. Either you can bundle all your assets correctly or store those assets in cloud and get the link of each asset from cloud.

*If you are trying second method, try uploading assets into a personal CSP like google drive/cloudfront and get the links.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I has multimodule project, which sets attributes in styles/themes from one of the imported libraries.
The problem is that, module in which we set this attributes doesn't import this library (in which attributes are located)

Issue can be fixed:

1. By importing this library (through `implementation(...)` in `dependency {...}` block in your module gradle file) into the module where reseted attributes are placed
2. By moving the code where we set these attributes to module that already import library, where they are declared

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I tried a lot) all I had to do is remove C:\Users\djdance\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28 and switch compileSdk to 29. Suddenly in Jan 2024 sdk 28 wont work anymore for me. It existed, lint can find resources, but AAPT can not build resources from 28 now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it got fixed after adding "ic_push_small.xml"  in drawable folder

```
\Platforms\Android\Resources\drawable\ic_push_small.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

copy "res" folder from another project (where is res folder - android/app/src/main) paste your own project. re run.

Answer (score -1):

copy drawable folder all file and paste drawable_v24 folder your own project. re run. I hope this is work.