# Need Some Help for: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

> Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\Yoan\firebaseapp\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:49:
>   AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification (aka
>   com.firebaseapp:drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification) not found.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

res folder:
[image]

value folder:

[image]

strings.xml:

[image]

colors.xml:

[image]

styles.xml:

[image]

I read on couple of questions that if I have the first line in the .xml file twice I have to remove one, but what can I do in my case? I have it only once.

Comment: Can you update the question with a screenshot of the contents of your drawable folder?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing a file named `ic_stat_ic_notification` in your project.
Open your project.
Goto `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` and check if you have a file with name `ic_stat_ic_notification` or not...
if unavailable please add a file with that name within the drawable folder.
Suggestion:-
I would suggest your app icon with that name to be added in the drawable folder(as the name of file contains notification do it might be a notification icon file).

Comment: Actually my folder is missing

Comment: i read the conversation between you and the-dagger. So, did it work?

Comment: goto your string.xml file and paste this code:-
```<string name="default_notification_channel_id">Firebase</string>```

Comment: Okay looks like this works but now:> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Cannot create directory C:\Users\Yoan\firebaseapp\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values

Comment: can you show the images of all the xml files in values folder

Comment: Okay just a moment

Comment: is it possible for you to upload your project

Comment: In the terminal, goto your project location 
the run:-  ```cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android```

Comment: it doesn't recognize gradlew

Comment: it seems that you have too many lost files...
use ```react-native init newProjectName``` and transfer all the source files/folders there
eg:- ```package.json, index.js, index.android.js, App.js, app.json,android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest and android/app/src/main/java```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is add a new file to your `drawable` folder with the name `ic_stat_ic_notification.png` and then retry building the project.

I'd also suggest that you add a screenshot of your project structure to your original question so that we know what its contents are.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194821/discussion-on-answer-by-the-dagger-need-some-help-for-execution-failed-for-task).

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google of that error message lead me to this other SO post: [AAPT error: resource drawable/... not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965610/aapt-error-resource-drawable-not-found) which seems to mention some other potential reasons for getting this error in it's comments.

In particular, there is [some talk about line ending mismatches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965610/aapt-error-resource-drawable-not-found/49966867#49966867) that may apply to your situation? Other potential issues include [not having the correct API version set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965610/aapt-error-resource-drawable-not-found/52443833#52443833), or [missing files from your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965610/aapt-error-resource-drawable-not-found/54145064#54145064).

Given your error specifically mentions `com.firebaseapp:drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification`, my guess is that it's the last issue (missing files from your project), have you got the firebase SDK/resources correctly added?

Comment: I saw that but I didn't understand what actually he did, if you can help ?